# Not able to zoom in and out in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a newbie
I'm trying to zoom in using Ctrl+= but I'm getting a message "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again."
Clicking on "Open Setting" is opening another file named "{} setting.json 1", the code in that file is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int32_t main() {
    cout <<"Hello World!\n";
}
```

There is a red underline on #include
What should I do?

Comment: If one of the answers helped, please accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow, Nikhil!

For me `Ctrl-shift-plus` works to zoom in (hold control & shift, then press `+`, the *plus* button, which on the US standard keyboard shares a key with the equal sign). Then Ctrl with the minus button zooms back out.

Work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings file obviously contains some C++ code, that shouldn't be in there. Delete everything from the file and save it. This will remove the red "1" next to the file name, which is indicator that the file contains errors. Afterwards you should be able to set the zoom level again.